# Expression templates in Eigen

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I would like to understand how expression templates work in Eigen.
I understood that the sum of two dynamical double vectors is performed by something which looks like this :

```
CwiseBinaryOp< internal::scalar_sum_op<double>, VectorXd const, VectorXd const > operator+(VectorXd const & lhs, VectorXd const & rhs);
```

I also understood how the difference of two vectors is implemented.

I have two questions.

**1. How does the product of a vector by a scalar work?**

I have noticed that

```
CwiseBinaryOp< internal::scalar_product_op<double>, VectorXd const, VectorXd const >
```

exists but I have the feeling that it is only designed to perform componentwise operations between two vectors. Does it mean that the product of a vector by a scalar correspond to a unary operator, say

```
CwiseUnaryOp< internal::scalar_product_op<double>, VectorXd const, VectorXd const > ?
```

**2. Can template expressions be built from mixed operations?**

For example, in an expression like

```
x = u + (2*v + (v-w))
```

is it true that these operations are performed in a nested way like this?

- `v-w` leads to the construction of an instance of E1
- `2*v` leads to the construction of an instance of E2
- `2*v + (v-w)` leads to the construction of an instance of E3
- `u + (2*v + (u-w))` leads to the construction of an instance of E4
- `x = u + (2*v + (v-w))` calls

the constructor

```
VectorXd(E4 const &);
```

or the overloading

```
VectorXd & operator=(E4 const &);
```

which evaluates the tree built from the previous steps, with the following aliases:

```
using diff = internal::scalar_difference_op<double>;
using prod = internal::scalar_product_op<double>;
using sum = internal::scalar_sum_op<double>;

using E1 = CwiseBinaryOp< diff, VectorXd const, VectorXd const >;
using E2 = CwiseUnaryOp< prod, VectorXd const >;
using E3 = CwiseBinaryOp< sum, E1 const, E2 const >;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. How does the product of a vector by a scalar work?**

In Eigen 3.2, it is implemented as a unary-operator, with a functor storing the value of the scalar factor. In Eigen 3.3, it is now implemented as a binary operator between the given matrix expression and a constant expression, something like:

```
CwiseBinaryOp<scalar_product_op<double,double>,
              VectorXd,
              CwiseNullaryOp<scalar_constant_op<double>, VectorXd> >
```

This approach permits to clearly distinguish between `s*vec` and `vec*s`, and the return type of, e.g., `vec*s` is equivalent to the one of `vec*VectorxD::Constant(vec.size(),s)`.

**2. Can template expressions be built from mixed operations?**

Your understanding is correct: first the expressions E1 to E4 are created, then the evaluation starts from the overloaded `operator=` generating a code like:

```
for(i=0;i<x.size();++i)
  x[i] = E4.coeff(i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!